# What is Calendar Legend block for? enabled but shows nothing

Tags: 7, datetime

Playing around with Calendar + Date.

There is a block called Calendar Legend, but shows nothing. **What is it for? Where should I configure?**, I checked the block configuration and views setup, no clues.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Legend is used on the large calendar page view to help denote between content types or taxonomy. You can set the colours of the content types or taxonomy by editing the view at /admin/structure/views/view/calendar/edit and select Format > Show > Settings

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This block is useful if you have different event types. It should show a color coded legend of the different event types displayed by the calendar.

If you are using it for taxonomy, there are [open issues](http://drupal.org/node/1161632) on this module.

Hope that helps, happy coding!